# JQDateRangeSlider change start/end value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working with DateRangeSlider for a couple of days and now I'm using it as a time slider - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dana15/LJrYf/148/)

My problem is that the min time is 02:00 and it needs to be 00:00, and max time is 01:59 instead of 23:59.

If I changed the formatter values from

```
h = val.getHours(),
m = val.getMinutes();
```

to

```
h = val.getUTCHours(),
m = val.getUTCMinutes();
```

it displays the correct start-end hour but when I'm getting those values:

```
var values = $("#slider").dateRangeSlider('values');
var test = values.min;
```

it still gets the other values: 02:00 instead of 00:00.

Is there any way to format the min/max value but when the values are read to display the same hour?

Comment: did you check my answer? It was the first one and I'm sure its correct.

Comment: Dekel - I've also checked your answer but the problem for it was that the default values were also +2 hours in advance, and also in the case where I changed the min and max bounds.

Comment: And this is exactly what my solution gives you. The +2hours is related to the timezone you are in. The solution in my answer will make sure your code will work for every date and every timezone (no matter where you are in), and you don't need to split the string into (year, month, day) etc... You can use your original values without string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take into account the TimeZone and also the Daylight Saving Time (the `Date()` object is relied on them).

Your solution can be:

```
var minDateStr = "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z";
var maxDateStr = "2014-01-01T23:59:00Z";
var min2 = new Date(new Date(minDateStr).getTime() + new Date(minDateStr).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000),
    max2 = new Date(new Date(maxDateStr).getTime() + new Date(maxDateStr).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

Here is a fix to your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/z1govrt7/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated format for date and time as below

```
var min2 = new Date(2014, 0, 1, 00, 00, 00),
    max2 = new Date(2014, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59);
```

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/LJrYf/149/ fiddle now.

I have updated your code and now its working as expected.